# Eval method in PyTorch loading

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, eval

I have a weird experience today. I trained a model in PyTorch and then I tested that with test samples. In this step, I got good results (imagine X). Then I save the model and load the model to see that I can get the same results (X) with the saved model.
Unfortunately, after loading the model, the results are worse (not X). I tested these (please do not discuss them) to fix the problem:

- I saved with different methods --> whole model, parameter dictionary
- Seed the same randomization in training and testing
- Switch from CPU to GPU and return
- Using grad zero and so on

Finally, I could figure out the problem. The problem was that I should turn the evaluation off in the loading model step. It means that in the loading section, I do not need to use torch.eval(). I know that eval() effects on Dropout layers and so on in training and evaluation modes.

My question is that when I have no dropout layer in my model, why torch.eval() works for me in reverse?
I have BatchNormalization in my model, I couldn't find the effect of eval() method on BatchNorm and DropOut on the PyTorch website.

In general, my question is that I read that in the loading model section, I should use eval() mode. However, why in my case, it is the opposite?

Comment: Did you not turn `eval` on for evaluation in training, i.e. while evaluating `X`?

Comment: I am talking about testing, not evaluation. In testing with test samples, there are two results for me. One when I test the model after training without saving the model. Another when I save the trained model and load it again. After investigation, I see that the problem is with the eval() method. Therefore, after loading my model, if I do not use a torch.eval() at all, then I will get the same results in both the aforementioned situations. My question is not how to solve the problem. The question is that I expect to use eval after loading to change the model in evaluation mode.